# How can I read the this.text from a drop-down list

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor

I have a drop down list and I want on change to read the .text property.

This is my javascript where I want to read the .text and .value

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#FCodeID").on("change", function () {
      var input = this.text;
      var comma = input.replace(",",".");
      var mb = comma.replace(" MB", "");
      var fields = mb.split('-');
      var size = fields[2];
      var url = "../MaterialsFiles" + this.value;
      if (size <= 10) {
        $('#pdfviewer').attr('src', url);
        $("#pdfviewer").show();
      }
      else {
        var filepath = this.value.replace("/","\\");
        document.getElementById("#demo").innerHTML = "Some text " + "\\\\192.168.1.191\\Materials Project\\" + filepath;
      }
    })
  })
</script>
```

If I change the `var input = this.text;` with `var input = "some string";` my js works fine.

But when I use the this.text I get input as null.

Comment: There's no `text` property available on a [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) (and that's what `this` is). Should this be [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) from jQuery? If so, then you first have to convert `this` into a jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks for that, I had to use this.name. After reading about  [HTMLSelectElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement), I figure that out.

Comment: One more question how can I make ```javascript var filepath = this.value.replace("/","\\");``` to replace all the instance of the "/"?

Comment: Comments are not meant to be short "Q&A sessions". Search for "javascript string replace all occurrences"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution on how to read the text from a drop down list value

```
<option value=value>sometext</option>
```

```
var e = document.getElementById("ddl");
var input = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

input = sometext